# subscribe is not defined------ Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

Am new to angular and am learning Angular6 tutorials from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LmIsbzt-S_E&index=21&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwhBRAgFinJR8KHIrCdTkZcZ).

Am getting the below error,

[image]

I want to display the list of employees there below the list's, and I am trying to resolve the error.

Below is the component code,

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Sai! To make it easier for people to help you, please write your code, errors, and anything else directly in the question instead of linking pictures.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Just put the code itself in your question. We can't copy-paste from a picture to try and figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a Reference error like on your picture, it could be because the variable that you try to run the function on doesn't have this function implemented.

The observable is probably not correctly implemented in your code.

I would make sure you have imported the Observable definitions from the library.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

and also define it as an Observable in the beginning of your class.

```
theObservableYouTryToSubscribeTo: Observable<any>
```

Once these two steps has been completed you should be able to run the subscribe function if it is a valid observable.

To learn and experiment with Observables, I like to use httpClient against 
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

Here is an example that I just googled. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-client

Comment: Thanks for the reply jg80.

Comment: Hi jg80, can you explain the point you mentioned, theObservableYouTryToSubscribeTo: Observable<any>.   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry did not see the comment until now. Have you solved your problem? It looks to me like your service is not actually returning an observable..do you have any code?